# error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4 when starting Opera Mobile Emulator

Tags: software-installation

Apparently the Opera Mobile Emulator is a 32-bit program and Ubuntu 13.10 no longer contains the "a32-libs" package to provide this support.

I have downloaded and unzipped the files, but when I try to run the emulator I get the following **error** message:

```
./opera-mobile-emulator-launcher: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have searched all over and have found all sorts of package-lists that one should install in order to run 32-bit programs on 13.10. I have tried several, but they have all failed because it seems that the list of packages that you need to run a specific program is specific to that program.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 16):

Unless you are using an architecture different to the rest of your system just executing `sudo apt-get install libqtgui4` should suffice.

In case that you are using another architecture just append `:arch` to the package name. Example, if you are using the 64-bits version then `libqtgui4:amd64` is for you:

```
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4:amd64
```

Comment: If you are using another system (like ARM) try sudo apt-get install libqtgui4